# What makes a subnet into a private subnet in AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

I want to have two public and two private subnets. What makes the difference between them too in Cloudformation or generally?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html *"If a subnet's traffic is routed to an internet gateway, the subnet is known as a public subnet."* and *"If a subnet doesn't have a route to the internet gateway, the subnet is known as a private subnet"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html

> If a subnet's traffic is routed to an internet gateway, the subnet is known as a public subnet

> If a subnet doesn't have a route to the internet gateway, the subnet is known as a private subnet

However you can still establish a connection to the internet from private subnet - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html

> The instances in the public subnet can send outbound traffic directly to the Internet, whereas the instances in the private subnet can't. Instead, the instances in the private subnet can access the Internet by using a network address translation (NAT) gateway that resides in the public subnet.

So in the CloudFormation the difference is in the `routes` of your route table for given subnet - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/cloudformation-vpc-template.html

`InternetGateway` is set as the destination for the `DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0` of the `DefaultPublicRoute` which is part of `PublicRouteTable` that is associated with the `PublicSubnet1` via `PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation`.

`NatGateway1` is set as the destination for the `DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0` of the `DefaultPrivateRoute1` which is part of `PrivateRouteTable` that is associated with the `PrivateSubnet1` via `PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation`.